# remapping and grouping repeated values from an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am trying to remap an response from a query to the database and group like items in one array.  for example, from this example below.

Response:

```
[
    "Location"=> "City 1",
    "AptDate"=> "2020-09-16",
    "AptTime"=> "11:00",
    "AptLength"=> "45",
    "AptStatus"=> "1",
    "Operatory"=> "1 RECALL",
    "OperatoryNum"=> "2"
],    
[
    "Location"=> "City 2",
    "AptDate"=> "2020-09-16",
    "AptTime"=> "09:00",
    "AptLength"=> "45",
    "AptStatus"=> "1",
    "Operatory"=> "1 RECALL",
    "OperatoryNum"=> "2"
],
[
    "Location"=> "City 1",
    "AptDate"=> "2020-09-16",
    "AptTime"=> "12:00",
    "AptLength"-> "45",
    "AptStatus"=>"1",
    "Operatory"=> "1 RECALL",
    "OperatoryNum"=> "2"
[,
```

looping through results:

```
           $remappedData=[];
                foreach ($result as $value)
                {
                    $remappedData[] = [
                        'location' => $value['Location'],

                        // And so on
                    ];

                }

}
```

This doesnt really give me what i need as I am trying to group the array based on Location and add the AppDate base on that location.  Something like this.

```
    {
        "Location": "City 1",
        "AptDate": ["2020-09-16","2020-09-16"],
        "AptTime": ["11:00","12:00"],
        "AptLength": ["45","45"],
        "AptStatus": ["1","1"],
        "Operatory": ["1 RECALL","1 RECALL"],
        "OperatoryNum": ["2","2"]
    },
    {
        "Location": "City 2",
        "AptDate": ["2020-09-16"],
        "AptTime": ["09:00"],
        "AptLength":[ "45"],
        "AptStatus": ["1"],
        "Operatory": ["1 RECALL"],
        "OperatoryNum": "2"
    },
```

Comment: Do you notice that keys are not same `City 1` and `City1`. One of them has space between. If that is a typo, let us know. So we can look

Comment: @JitendraYadav yes, it is a typo, sorry about that.  I have fixed that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on your scenario, you want grouping on `Location` and group all other attributes by keeping them in array.

```
foreach ($result as $value)
{
   $remappedData[$value['Location']]['location'] = $value['Location'];
   $remappedData[$value['Location']]['AptDate'][] = $value['AptDate']; // Notice we're creating an array here.
   $remappedData[$value['Location']]['AptTime'][] = $value['AptTime'];
   // so on all other attributes which needs to be grouped.
}
```

Note: Here we've created index as `Location`. If we don't want `Location` as key, we want as array(may be for frontend) use below code.

```
$temp = [];
$remappedData=[];
$intCurrentIndex = -1;

foreach ($result as $value)
{
    if(isset($temp[$value['Location']])){
         $oldIndex = $temp[$value['Location']];
         $remappedData[$oldIndex]['AptDate'][] = $value['AptDate'];
         $remappedData[$oldIndex]['AptTime'][] = $value['AptTime'];
    }
    else{
          $temp[$value['Location']] = ++$intCurrentIndex;
          $remappedData[$intCurrentIndex]['location'] = $value['Location'];
          $remappedData[$intCurrentIndex]['AptDate'][] = $value['AptDate'];
          $remappedData[$intCurrentIndex]['AptTime'][] = $value['AptTime'];
    }
  
}
```

Comment: what would the temporary array be?

Comment: Mostly in front end too, we don't need any manipulation, we can for for of loop. But just in case keys are not required. then array would be like `["location"=>"index_in_remappedData"..]`, so in loop we'll check whether key is set or not. If not we'll create new array otherwise we'll pick the key and directly add all attributes in same way we're doing.

Comment: What ill be doing is grabbing this reponse and displaying it in a Table and columns.

Comment: Then I think it will work, but if it doesn't, let me give you that solution too. Updating my answer.

Comment: How would I be able to also sort them by date?  same concept but include the date

Comment: Please create another question, and expected output. You can use initial data from this question itself.

Comment: I did https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63945802/remmaping-an-array-to-include-certain-values-in-php I used your same data