# Remmaping an array to include certain values in php

Tags: php, arrays, reactjs, foreach

I have the following foreach

```
$temp = [];
    $remappedData=[];
    $intCurrentIndex = -1;

    foreach ($result as $value)
    {
        if(isset($temp[$value['Location']])){
            $oldIndex = $temp[$value['Location']];
            $remappedData[$oldIndex]['AptDate'][] = $value['AptDate'];
            $remappedData[$oldIndex]['AptTime'][] = $value['AptTime'];
        }
        else{
            $temp[$value['Location']] = ++$intCurrentIndex;
            $remappedData[$intCurrentIndex]['location'] = $value['Location'];
            $remappedData[$intCurrentIndex]['AptDate'][] = $value['AptDate'];
            $remappedData[$intCurrentIndex]['AptTime'][] = $value['AptTime'];
        }

    }
```

This sorts all the data by location along with its aptDates and times.  Example:

```
[
   {
      "location":"Location 1",
      "AptDate":[
         "2020-09-17",
         "2020-09-17",
         "2020-09-17",
         "2020-09-17",
         "2020-09-17",
         "2020-09-17",
         "2020-09-17",
         "2020-09-17",
         "2020-09-17",
         "2020-09-17",
         "2020-09-17",
         "2020-09-18",
         "2020-09-18",
         "2020-09-18",
         "2020-09-18",
         "2020-09-18",
         "2020-09-18",
         "2020-09-18",
         "2020-09-18",
         "2020-09-18"
      ],
      "AptTime":[
         "15:15",
         "15:45",
         "15:30",
         "15:30",
         "16:15",
         "15:15",
         "15:45",
         "14:45",
         "15:15",
         "16:00",
         "14:45",
         "08:30",
         "09:30",
         "10:15",
         "12:30",
         "13:30",
         "14:30",
         "15:45",
         "08:00",
         "09:00"
      ]
   }
]
```

This sorts them by location but i am trying to keep this format but also include the times with the dates.

```
 [
       {
          "location":"Location 1",
          "AptDate": [
              "2020-09-17" : [
                   "15:15",
                   "15:45",
                   "15:30",
                   "15:30",
                   "16:15",
                   "15:15",
                   "15:45",
                   "14:45",
                   "15:15",
                   "16:00",
               ],
              "2020-09-18" :[
                  "08:30",
                  "09:30",
                  "10:15",
                  "12:30",
                  "13:30",
                  "14:30",
                  "15:45",
                  "08:00",
                  "09:00"
               ]
           ]
       }
    ]
```

What I have tried so far is not working. I adding the location and checking if is set but it sorts them by each individual aptdate, which is not what I need.
[value now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blhA8.png)

Trying to display this in a react-table but I am getting an error saying `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

```
const Cell = ({ cell }) => {
  return cell.row.original.AptDate.map((value, index) => (
      <span
          key={index}
          style={{ display: "grid", textAlign:"center", marginRight: index === 0 ? 8 : 0 }}
      >
      {value}
    </span>
  ));
};
```

Trying to add this to a table like this.

[image: front end talbe]

Comment: I'll update the question for input data, please update the expected output for the same.

Comment: Scenario i'm talking about is, what if there are multiple dates in any order and corresponding times also not sorted. What will be output you're expecting?

Comment: @JitendraYadav ok, I updated the expected scenario

Comment: There can't be two keys with same name in an object. Over here you've set `AptDate` and `AptTime` two times.

Comment: @JitendraYadav is there a way to organize the array by location and date and have their respective times?

Comment: yes,  let me update your expected output. If that works for you, we can go ahead.

Comment: check the updated output, if that works, we'll look into that

Comment: @JitendraYadav Yes, thats it.

Comment: can you include some frontend code  and how you want to display that then we can atleast try what should be formatted array to support that

Comment: @JitendraYadav ok, thank you so much. I added front end.  I think is an issue with mapping over it.

Comment: previously we're getting value of `aptdate` in `value` but now `value` in your map function is an array and its key represents `aptdate`.

Comment: are you creating a table in front end for the same?

Comment: @JitendraYadav yes I am....or trying to.  With react-table

Comment: so how you want to display these data?

Comment: I think now you have only one column `aptDate`. and you have an object which contains keys as `aptDate` and values `aptTime` which are again array.

Comment: would you be creating a small table or something inside single column?

Comment: @JitendraYadav Yea, I added a picture of what I am trying to do in the front end

Comment: okay, so you  will be fetching data for a week. then for each location you'll add timings for each day. right?

Comment: @JitendraYadav, yes, thats correct.

Comment: @JitendraYadav done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your frontend, what we can do it. Create an array of dates & times based on day like monday, tuesday and so on.

we can get day by following code.

```
echo date('D', strtotime('2020-09-18'));

Output: Fri
```

We will make it as key and bind data and its time accordingly. We will generate keys like `Fri_date`, `Sat_date` and times like `Fri_time`, `Sat_time` which you can directly use for each week day column.

```
foreach ($result as $value)
{
    $strDay = date('D', strtotime($value['AptDate']));
    if(isset($temp[$value['Location']])){
        $oldIndex = $temp[$value['Location']];
        $remappedData[$oldIndex][$strDay. '_date'] = $value['AptDate'];
        $remappedData[$oldIndex][$strDay. '_time'][] = $value['AptTime'];
    }
    else{
        $temp[$value['Location']] = ++$intCurrentIndex;
        $remappedData[$intCurrentIndex]['location'] = $value['Location'];
        $remappedData[$intCurrentIndex][$strDay. '_date'] = $value['AptDate'];
        $remappedData[$intCurrentIndex][$strDay. '_time'][] = $value['AptTime'];
   }

}
```

Comment: it looks like the date is an object key, therefore rendering in the front end its tricky

Comment: I added a picuture in the original question.

Comment: Let me see. If so, you need to provide an expected output. So we can work on that

Comment: picture contains data as expected. I think you have some other constraints in your front end. Until we know, how we arrange data to support front-end. We don't know how to go further.